# Pressure and temperature of environment or system in the definition of chemical potentials?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

According to Schroeder's book, 'P' is the pressure of the environment in H=U+PV and 'T' is the temperature of environment in F=U-TS. When I look up online it turns out that these are the properties of the system not the environment. So what are these quantities related to actually?

Comment: Can you give an example where it is said T is the property of the system?

Comment: Schroeder defines it in such a way that F=U-TS and he explicitly writes that T is the temperature of the environment.

Comment: Any online link showing T is system's property?

Comment: I couldn't find one. But I found one for enthalpy where it said that P was the pressure of system. Also, Schroeder uses the identities for these thermodynamic potentials as if the pressure and temperature being talked about were of the system. It turns out that the pressure and temperature of the system and environment are the same.

Comment: I think P is the property of the system and T is the property of the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are properties of a system that is in *equilibrium* with its environment. That means the pressure and temperature etc. of the system and environment must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

From Clausius' Inequality $$\oint \frac{đQ_\textrm{system}}{T_\textrm{source}}\leqq 0\tag{I }$$

it can be deduced $$S(\mathrm B) - S(\mathrm A)\geqq \int_\mathrm A^\mathrm B \frac{đQ}{T},\tag {II}$$
where $\mathrm{ A,~B} $ are initial and final equilibrium states.

(Note, $T$ is actually $T_\textrm{source/environment}$ which need not be equal to the temperature $T_\textrm{system}$ of the system or part of the system  which exchanges the thermal energy but when the transformation is reversible, then only$T_\textrm{source/environment}= T_\textrm{system}$.)

Suppose, now, the system exchanges thermal energy from source at constant temperature $T;$ so $$Q \leqq T~[S(\mathrm B)- S(\mathrm A)]\tag{III} $$

This acts as the *upper limit* of the amount of thermal energy the system can exchange.

From the First Law of Thermodynamics,  $$W\leqq U(\mathrm A) - (\mathrm B) + T~[S(\mathrm B)- S(\mathrm A)] \tag{IV}$$

Suppose,both the initial and final equilibrium states have the same temperature as that of the source viz. $T$.

Define $F = U-TS$

Then, from $\mathrm{(IV)},$ $$W\leqq F(\mathrm A)- F(\mathrm B)\tag V$$

What can be concluded from the following above discussion?

It is that $T$ in the definition of $F$ is the temperature of the source/environment and as that in the initial and final  equilibrium states, the system assumes the temperature $T$ of the source/environment.

---

### References:

$\bullet$ *Thermodynamics* by *E.Fermi*.